# Difference between 2 numbers and return a %

Tags: sql

I'm Looking to see if I can return a % from the following, but it need finishing.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM VEHICLES_FW
WHERE ARCHIVE_STATUS_FW = 'N'
AND LOCATION_CODE_FW IN ('L0078')
```

This brings me back the amount of vehicle on this location. I know that the location has a limit of 180.

How do I write in so it works out that the % is 31%?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, how i don't know what SQL variant you use, I write my response how I'll write on SQL Server.

If you want % respect of limit (180)

```
DECLARE @PERCENTAGE DECIMAL --Or INT if you prefer it

SET @PERCENTAGE = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM VEHICLES_FW
WHERE ARCHIVE_STATUS_FW = 'N'
AND LOCATION_CODE_FW IN ('L0078')) * (100 / 180)

RETURN PERCENTAGE;
```

If you want % respect all cars

```
DECLARE @PERCENTAGE DECIMAL --Or INT if you prefer it
DECLARE @TOTAL DECIMAL --Or INT if you prefer it

SET @TOTAL = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM VEHICLES_FW)

SET @PERCENTAGE = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM VEHICLES_FW
WHERE ARCHIVE_STATUS_FW = 'N'
AND LOCATION_CODE_FW IN ('L0078')) * (100 / 180)

RETURN PERCENTAGE;
```